# Eleventy is not adding an html suffix to index files generated from a nested index.md file

Tags: eleventy, ssg

Eleventy is not adding an `html` suffix to index files generated from a nested index.md file.

For example, here is a sample directory structure with my source content ...

```
|
+- /src (input dir)
    |
    +- post
    |   |
    |   +- my-cool-post
    |       |
    |       +- /images
    |       |
    |       +- index.md
    |
    +- index.md
    |
    +- about.md
```

When I then run the command `npx eleventy` I get the following output ...

```
|
+- /public (output dir)
    |
    +- post
    |   |
    |   +- my-cool-post
    |       |
    |       +- /images
    |       |
    |       +- index <---- NOTE there is no ".html" suffix on this file
    |
    +- index.html <----- this file is ok however
    |
    +- about.html <----- and so is this file
```

This is how I have my `.eleventy.js` configuration file setup ..

```js
// Data Extensions
const yaml = require("js-yaml");

module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {

  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("_assets");
  eleventyConfig.addWatchTarget("./src/_sass/");
  eleventyConfig.addDataExtension("yaml", contents => yaml.safeLoad(contents));
  eleventyConfig.setTemplateFormats([
    "md",
    "css",
    "jpg",
    "png",
    "webp",
    "svg",
    "html"
  ]);
  return {
    jsDataFileSuffix: ".11ty",
    dataTemplateEngine: "njk",
    htmlTemplateEngine: "njk",
    markdownTemplateEngine: "njk",
    passthroughFileCopy: true,
    dir: {
      input: "src",
      data: "_data",
      includes: "_includes",
      layouts: "_layouts",
      output: "public"
    }
  }
}
```

Without the `*.html` suffix the url `http://../post/my-cool-post` returns a 404 error.  If I manuall add the `*.html` suffix then it works.

Any idea what is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.  In the example above, there was a file in `/src/post/post.yaml` that had this value:

```
permalink: "{{ page.filePathStem }}"
```

The reason I had this in there was to create an alias `permalink` that I could use in my templates instead of having to type out `{{ page.filePathStem }}`.  As it turns out, `permalink` is a reserved property and clearly has an effect on rendering output.  Removing the line form the file fixed the issue.